# Telerik Controls not working after Overriding Page Render

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik, telerik-grid

Yesterday I was doing something and found this unexpected behavior with the Telerik controls as soon as override the page render. I see the grids sorting and telerik ajax not working when I have coded the following code.
I would really appreciate if any one has clue why this is happening for the following code snippet.

```
  protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    // setup a TextWriter to capture the markup
    TextWriter tw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);
    // render the markup into our surrogate TextWriter
    base.Render(htw);
    // get the captured markup as a string
    string pageSource = tw.ToString();
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(pageSource, @"\[\!\[(.*?)\]\!\]");
    List<string> finishedCaptures = new List<string>();
    // Use foreach loop.
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        foreach (Capture capture in match.Captures)
        {
            if (!finishedCaptures.Contains(capture.Value))
            {
                pageSource = pageSource.Replace(capture.Value, ConfigFactory.Instance[capture.Value.Trim(new char[] { '[', ']', '!' })]);
                finishedCaptures.Add(capture.Value);
            }
        }
    }
    writer.Write(pageSource);
}
```

-Thanks for your precious time.

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any unintended consequences, namely that the regex is matching something it shouldn't, and subsequently replacing it?  What are the values you are trying to match, and what are you matching it with?

Comment: I am sure they are not...